# setting aws-lex request attributes with aws-sdk-ios

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lex, aws-sdk-ios

Is there a way to set request attributes with iOS SDK? I am using this on android:

```java
textInForAudioOut(java.lang.String text, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> sessionAttributes, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> requestAttributes)
```

but i can't find the equivalent in iOS. 
Is there another way to add request attributes to requests in iOS?

Comment: I think is sessionAttributes

Comment: sessionAttributes persist for the duration of the session, i need requestAttributes to add keys for specific requests in session

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWSLexPostTextRequest or AWSLexPostContentRequest, you can set it on the request object

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/518ad4d1506ee696965a5e57973e2d4226d835a5/AWSLex/AWSLexModel.m#L439